# How to retrieve the particular row of detailsview into textbox on page load event if details view defaultmode is readonly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to retrieve the particular row of detailsview into textbox on page load event if details view defaultmode  is readonly

[image]

i want to retrieve the email id from detailsview email row in textbox1 on page load event ?

Comment: Show us your code, explain what isn't working and what you are having difficulties with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to access the [DataItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.dataitem.aspx) in the RowDataBound like:

```
DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)DetailsView1.DataItem;
string myfield = (string)dr["YourFieldName"];
```

Another way is get the item from [Rows.Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.rows%28VS.80%29.aspx) like:

```
DetailsViewRow row = DetailsView1.Rows[youremailrowindex];
String email= row.Cells[youremailcellindex].Text;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    TextBox1.Text = DetailsView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Text
End Sub
```

Make sure you realize that with a DetailsView, the max "Cells" value is 1. Look at it as if you were pulling and SQL query and these are the rows that are output.

```
Row = Up and down (starting with 0)

Cells = Column (0 or 1)
```